# Wordpress Social icon hide when empty

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I'm making this system when the entered href is empty, the icon will be hidden, but for me this is not working,

I tried some methodes, but non worked. Anyone knows whats wrong?

I've got this code:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer-text">Copyright &copy; website.nl - 2017/2017
    <?php if (!empty(get_theme_mod('website_url2'))): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'website_url1' ) ); ?>" class="social1">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</footer>
```

Comment: You example isn't displaying correctly.  Could you check your formatting?

Comment: @Dedering fixed =)

Comment: Wait, you're checking if 'pocketcars_url2 is not null then displaying 'pocketcars_url1'?

Answer (score 0):

Your operator is incorrect: `if (!get_theme_mod(('pocketcars_url2') == '' ))`

Try this: `if ( get_theme_mod(('pocketcars_url1') != '' ))`

```
    <?php if ( trim( get_theme_mod('pocketcars_url1' ) ) != '' ) : ?>  
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'pocketcars_url2' ) );?>" class="social1">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>"
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Alright updated the post @Dedering cause now the icon is hidden forever

Comment: @/pieter-bernarnd Just updated my example. Does that fix it?

Comment: Fixed it =) look answer

Comment: @pieter-bernarnd You might want to add a trim() to avoid a false positive from an errant single space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $text = esc_url(get_theme_mod( 'website_url1' )); if($text != '' ) : ?>
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'website_url2' ) );?>" class="social1">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>"
<?php endif; ?>
```